# How to insert rows when using a many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, schema, insert

Given the following, how could I insert rows in my db? (Or what should I correct in my schema?)

Models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many                            :tran_items
    has_many :transactions, :through => :tran_items
end
class TranItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :transaction
end
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base #answer: rename Transaction
    has_many                            :tran_items
    has_many :items, :through =>        :tran_items
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table :items do |t|
  t.references :tran_items #answer: remove this line
  t.string     :name
end
create_table :tran_items do |t|
  t.belongs_to :items,  :transactions,  :null => false #answer: unpluralize
  t.integer    :quantity
end
create_table :transactions do |t|
  t.references :tran_items #answer: remove this line
  t.decimal    :profit
end
```

I lost a few hours trying to insert records, using the rails console to test things out.

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665389/how-to-save-to-database-with-associations-in-rails-protecting-mass-assigment/11681454#11681454

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(edit: the model name "Transaction" may cause you some problems due to ActiveRecord::Transactions. [There is a lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/993-having-column-named-transaction-in-a-model-leads-to-weird-behavior).)

Your schema is not set up correctly. "references" is an alias to "belongs_to". Item and Transaction don't **belong_to** trans_items, they each **has_many** trans_items (according to your models)

```
create_table :items do |t|
  t.string     :name
end
create_table :tran_items do |t|
  t.belongs_to :item, :transaction, :null    => false
  t.integer    :quantity
end
create_table :transactions do |t|
  t.decimal    :profit,  :default => 0
end
```

(edit: make belongs_to singular)

Did you drop the db and re-run the migrations to build the new schema?

rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate

Here is what I get in the console:

```
>> i = Item.create(:name => 'My Item')    
=> #<Item id: 2, name: "My Item">
>> t = Transaction.create(:profit => 100)
=> #<Transaction id: 2, profit: #<BigDecimal:2411d2c,'0.1E3',4(8)>>
>> t.tran_items.create(:item => i)
=> #<TranItem id: nil, item_id: 2, transaction_id: 2, quantity: nil>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm able to insert items and transactions, separately (without any relation between them), which is obviously wrong, but a good start. I'm yet to find how to make something like this work, though: item.transactions << Transaction.create(...)

Comment: I were back-migrating and migrating to the latest version afterwards; I tried drop-create-migrate and then ran exactly what you run, and still get the exact same error about item= being undefined. Incredible... I think I'll try renaming Transaction like you said.

Comment: Ok, I remarked that through my latest tests, I had pluralized some hashes that shouldn't be, in hope it would solve the pluralization issues; dropping the db & fixing the remaining pluralization issues solved everything. (And I renamed Transaction too.) I think I'll turn off pluralization in future!

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Mike. I also found out I can do a i.transactions << Transaction.create(...), which feels very elegant to me.

Comment: Thanks, bro it helped.

Answer (score 2):

This schema should give you the results you are looking for:

```
   create_table :items do |t|
      t.string     :name
    end
    create_table :purchase_items do |t|
      t.belongs_to :item, :purchase, :null    => false
      t.integer    :quantity
    end
    create_table :purchases do |t|
      t.decimal    :profit,                :default => 0
    end
```

Here are the models:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many                            :purchase_items
    has_many :items, :through =>        :purchase_items
end   

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many                            :purchase_items
    has_many :purchases, :through => :purchase_items
end

class PurchaseItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :purchase
end
```

Now using the console:

```
>> i = Item.create(:name => 'Item One')
=> #<Item id: 1, name: "Item One">
>> p = Purchase.create(:profit => 100)
=> #<Purchase id: 1, profit: #<BigDecimal:2458cf4,'0.1E3',4(8)>>
>> p.purchase_items.create(:item => i)
=> #<PurchaseItem id: 1, item_id: 1, purchase_id: 1, quantity: nil>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly.

```
item = Item.new(:name => "item")
item.transactions.build(:name => "transaction")
item.save!
```

Comment: I replaced your second `:name => "transaction"` for `:profit => 10`, and got this when I save: `transactions.tran_items_id may not be NULL`