# How to save to Database with associations in rails protecting mass assignment

Tags: ruby, many-to-many, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2, one-to-many

After trying for few hours I can not save to the database.

The context is this:
I have two types of users, one for that I only need very basic information [Username, email, password] and another kind of user for who I need a lot of information [age, gender, city and so on]

I did not use STI becouse of the vast quantity of Null values there would be in the table.
So I created this three modes in which a user has a profile (profiles table) or not depending of its type [1 or 2], and a field of this profile is the city this user is living in, that relates to another table in the DB, the cities table

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_one :city, through: :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
  [...a bunch of fields here]
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :users, through: :profiles
end
```

When I play with them in the rails console everything goes OK:

```
usr = User.new(name: "roxy", email: "roxy@example.me", password: "roxanna", password_confirmation: "roxanna", utype: 1)
cty = City.new(name: "Bucaramanga")
prf = Profile.new (rname: "Rosa Juliana Diaz del Castillo"...)
prf.city = cty
usr.profile = prf
usr.valid?
=> true
usr.save
=> true
```

but when I try to save in the app (View an Model)

```
<%= f.label :city, "En que ciudad te encuentras?"%>
<%= select_tag :city, options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, 'id', "name"),{:prompt => 'Selecciona tu ciudad'}%>

def new
  @profile = Profile.new
end

def create
  @profile = params[:profile]
  @city= City.find_by_id(params[:city].to_i)
  @profile.city = @city
end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `city=' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0xa556fe0>
```

Can someone please help me?

**UPDATE**
As David suggested I created the Profile object in the first line of the create method, so my controller now look like this:

```
def create
  @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
  @city= City.find_by_id(params[:city].to_i)
  @profile.city = @city
  @usr = current_user
  if @usr.profile.exists? @profile
    @usr.errors.add(:profile, "is already assigned to this user") # or something to that effect
    render :new
  else 
   @usr.profile << @profile
   redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

But I'm getting this error now

```
undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass
```

current_user returns the @current_user

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

Could you tell me please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: check out the documentation for accepts_nested_attributes_for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to write this to all of you who are beginning as well as I am and are stuck in this step.

I had to create a new project and play with it to realize what I was doing wrong. I figured out that I was validating a last time field I added to the `Profiles` table and had

```
# education       :string(255)     not null
```

but I had not added it yet to the form so the error launched is:

```
Failed to save the new associated so_profile.
```

Now, you know if you got this error, go check your schema and look for NOT_NULL fields you might be missing in the form, also you can comment out all your model validations and after it's working uncomment'em to be sure.

So, my Final Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_one :city, through: :profile
  attr_accessible :email, :name
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
  attr_accessible :age, :fcolor, :gender
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :users, through: :profiles
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

My controllers:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
    city = City.find_by_id(params[:city])
    @profile.city = city
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:userid])
    @user.profile = @profile
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] =  "Guardado"
      redirect_to profile_path(id: @user.id)
    end
  end

  def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end  
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] =  "Registrado!"
      redirect_to new_profile_path(id: @user.id)
    else
      flash[:error] =  "No Registrado :("
      redirect_to new
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end
end
```

In a real app you have to use Cookies or something else to keep the session alive and therefore the user_token from where you get the user_id, but it works to play with associations.

The views:

profiles/new.html.erb

```
<%= @user.name %>
<%= form_for @profile, url: {action: :create, userid: @user.id } do |f| %>
<%= f.label :age, "Edad" %>
<%= f.text_field :age%> <br />

<%= label :city, "Ciudad"%>
<%= select_tag :city, options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, 'id', 'name')%>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

profiles/show.html.erb

```
Hello <%= @user.name %><br />
Tu edad es: <%= @user.profile.age %><br />
Vives en <%= @user.profile.city.name%>
```

users/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user do |f|%>
<%= f.label :name, "Nombre"%>
<%= f.text_field :name, size: 20, placeholder: "Escribe tu nombre aqui" %><br />

<%= f.label :email, "Email"%>
<%= f.text_field :email, size: 20, placeholder: "Escribe tu email aqui" %><br />

<%= f.submit "Sign me up!"%>
```

users/show.html.erb

```
Name: <%= @user.name %><br />
Email: <%= @user.email %>
```

And that's it!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to read the error messages.  The problem is that @profile is a hash because you didnt't actually create a new Profile object on the first line of the `create` method.

Comment: Thank you very much David, as I had created the Profile object in the new method, I thought I just could assign the values w/o creating a new one. It helped, but still can't get my code saving. Please could you tell me  the correct way to save when there are associations protecting FK from mass assigment. I updated my code.

Comment: It looks like I answered your original question so please accept my answer.  All you needed to do was add "Profile.new" into the right place on the line that assigned to @profile.  I have not looked into why this new feature you are trying add is failing, but that should be a separate question.

Comment: David, you gave me a clue and I thank you very much, but actually the question is How to save to Database with associations w/o passing the ids directly, it is protecting the attributes from mass assigment, an answer should hopefully include an explanation on how to write the create method, if you could do it quickly I am sure many of us will be very grateful

Answer (score -1):

I think that the correct is

```
@so_profile.City
```

not

```
@so_profile.city
```

Because the class name is City

Comment: Thank you Francisco, but it made no difference